# installing Java 5 SDK on Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit

Tags: java

I have an Hp/Compaq laptop, intel, 2 processors, using 64 bit.
I want to install Java 5 SDK, I see references to AMD 64 bit, I am assuming that is different from intel?
Is there a Java 5 sdk for my environment?

Answer (score 3):

You see AMD 64 because AMD developed a 64 bit architecture before Intel and thus the name amd64 stuck, but any binary labeled amd64 works on a Intel 64 bit processor.

You can download the amd64 build of the JDK and install it on your laptop without problems for running software such as Tomcat or Eclipse, however a 32-bit browser might not be able to run a 64-bit Java browser plugin (i.e. you may have problems running Java applets from a browser).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install just the runtime environment, but in seems to be an error, since I cannot start Eclipse. When I run the command "eclipse -vm" I get "Access is denied". In fact, Java SE is not supported for Windows Server 2008 R2: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/system-configurations-135212.html
So, we'll just have to wait to get it supported, untill then maibe win 7 x64 will be the alternative.